# PHP - Reverse of calling a function?

Tags: php, function, scope

Having some trouble with this..

```
<?php

EG204_ExoSkel();

function EG204_ExoSkel() { 

    $to_be_end = 'Red';

    everything_loop();

}

function everything_loop() {

    echo $to_be_end;

}

?>
```

The code above will not echo Red, so I must be trying to use functions backwards. Might that be possible?

All that is in the Everything function is to be apart of different foreach loops.

Comment: What you have to do is to learn about functions and scope and how to pass parameters to functions. http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one (send it as an argument)

```
<?php
EG204_ExoSkel();

function EG204_ExoSkel() {

    $to_be_end = 'Red';

    everything_loop($to_be_end);

}

function everything_loop($argument) {

    echo $argument;

}
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3c1b6.php

Comment: I suggest you rename the parameter in `everything_loop`. Otherwise the OP might not understand what is going on here.

Comment: Took the advice not to use globales, this seems work out, since there is only one value that needs to sent over.

Comment: @Suffice: If I helped you, please help me: **[accept my answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif)** (click on that link if you're not sure how to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing `$to_be_end` as a global!

**WARNING** *Global are bad practice* **Avoid**

```
<?php

EG204_ExoSkel();

function EG204_ExoSkel() { 

global $to_be_end;

$to_be_end = 'Red';

everything_loop();

}

function everything_loop() {

global $to_be_end;

echo $to_be_end;

}

?>
```

Comment: @Suffice: Don't use globales. They might seem to be a good solution at first, but they are not. See the note in Veger's answer. And this code won't work btw.

Comment: This is considered bad practice and is to be avoided if at all possible... Consider the other answers which recommend a better understanding of function scope.

Comment: what? the other answer is using `global`! and the one who did not use `global` changed the function declaration !

Comment: Proof: http://codepad.org/92wOn364. Changing the declaration is not bad. Using parameters is *much* better than using globals.

Comment: You need to add global in *both* functions in order to make it work. As said, better not use global variables as it tends to mess things up.

Comment: I edited (: ... it is bad practice but i dont think you can change the context of the question .. The only way to do so is using `Global`

Answer (score 0):

You have [scoping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issues. The declaration of `$to_be_end` is only available in the `EG204_ExoSkel` function.

If you want to use it outside that function you should use `global` to make it globally available. And also add global in the other function (also to made use of the global variable). Resulting in this:

```
EG204_ExoSkel();

function EG204_ExoSkel() { 
  global $to_be_end;    
  $to_be_end = 'Red';
  everything_loop();

}

function everything_loop() {
  global $to_be_end;
  echo $to_be_end;
}
```

**Note**: using global is considered *bad* practice and tends to make a mess of your code (and even introduce hard to find bugs). A better solution (if possible in your real code) is to pass on the variable to the other function(s).